# Soundcloud API Check if a user is following another user

Tags: php, json, api, soundcloud

I'm trying to figure out if a user is following another user on Soundcloud using the Soundcloud API and php.
So far I came across a solution which would either return an object (user) or a 404 error:

```
$test = json_decode($client->get('/users/{id1}/followers/{id2}'));
```

I've tried it multiple times with different user IDs but I always receive a the following error message:

```
'Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception' with message 'The requested URL responded with HTTP code 404.'
```

I know that this is supposed to be the error message which informs me that user2 is not following user1. However I've tried this snippet with ids where I know a reciprocal following exists for sure. 
Any suggestions on how this can be solved?

**Update (21.05.15):**

I've read through some of the Soundcloud documentation and cam across a code snippet:

```
<?php 
require_once 'Services/Soundcloud.php';
// create a client object with access token
$client = new Services_Soundcloud('YOUR_CLIENT_ID', 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET');
$client->setAccessToken('YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN');
// Follow user with ID 3207
$client->put('/me/followings/3207');
// Unfollow the same user
$client->delete('/me/followings/3207');
// check the status of the relationship
try {
$client->get('/me/followings/3207');
} catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
if ($e->getHttpCode() == '404')
    print "You are not following user 3207\n";
}
?>
```

This is pretty much what I was referring to. However if I open a php page with this script the result is always one of three cases:

1. You are not following user 3207 (expected output)
2. No output (I'm following the user)
3. Uncaught exception 'Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception' with message 'The requested URL responded with HTTP code 404.'

The third option is either referring to $client->put or $client->delete

Comment: i dont know why you first put and the delete the same user? i'd download the array of followers or people you follow and walk through this array if it contains the userid you wanna check.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i would do this:

```
<?php
require_once 'Services/Soundcloud.php';

$client = new Services_Soundcloud(
'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx160', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx34dd1 ');

$userid     = 1672444;
$followerid = 383228;
$yesno = '';

try {
  $response = json_decode($client->get('users/'.$userid.'/followers'), true);
  $yesno = IdInArray($response, $followerid);
  echo $yesno;
} catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
  exit($e->getMessage());
}

function IdInArray($response, $followerid){
echo $followerid.'<br/>';
  for($i = 0; $i < count($response); ++$i) {
    if($response[$i]['id'] == $followerid){
      return 'yolo';
    }
    else{
      return 'nolo';
    }
  }
}
?>
```